# Trying to scrape table from www.fangraphs.com using BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have successfully scraped a leaderboard table from said site, at this URL:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2022&month=1000&season1=2022&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2022-01-01&enddate=2022-09-13&sort=17,d

using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import numpy as np

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(start_date,end_date, URL_1):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a dataframe.
    """
    # parse input
    PITCHERS_URL = URL_1
    # request the data
    pitchers_html = requests.get(PITCHERS_URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pitchers_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})
    
    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)
    
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)

sdate = '2022-01-01'
enddate = date.today()
enddate =enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#date.today() - timedelta(1)
#enddate = enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
PITCHERS = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2022&month=1000&season1=2022&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate={}&enddate={}&sort=17,d".format(sdate, enddate)

wRC1 = parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(sdate, enddate, PITCHERS)
```

where the table is successfully assigned to the dataframe wRC1.

I'm trying to do something similar but with the following link:

https://www.fangraphs.com/players/trevor-rogers/22286/game-log?type=0&gds=2022-04-10&gde=2022-09-12&season=&position=P

using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import numpy as np

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(start_date,end_date, URL_1):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a dataframe.
    """
    # parse input
    PITCHERS_URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=c%2C13%2C7%2C8%2C120%2C121%2C331%2C105%2C111%2C24%2C19%2C14%2C329%2C324%2C45%2C122%2C6%2C42%2C43%2C328%2C330%2C322%2C323%2C326%2C332&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&startdate={}&enddate={}&page=1_2000".format(start_date, end_date)
    PITCHERS_URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2022&month=1000&season1=2022&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate={}&enddate={}&sort=17,d".format(start_date, end_date)
    PITCHERS_URL = URL_1
    # request the data
    pitchers_html = requests.get(PITCHERS_URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pitchers_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})
    
    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)
    
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)


sdate = '2022-01-01'
enddate = date.today()
enddate =enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#date.today() - timedelta(1)
#enddate = enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
PITCHERS = "https://www.fangraphs.com/players/trevor-rogers/22286/game-log?type=0&gds=2022-04-10&gde=2022-09-12&season=&position=P"

df = parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(sdate, enddate, PITCHERS)
```

But the program ends up producing the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

What could be producing this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data is being pulled dynamically by page' javascript, from an API endpoint. You can see that endpoint by inspecting Dev tools - Network tab in browser. Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://cdn.fangraphs.com/api/players/game-log?playerid=22286&position=P&type=0&season=&gds=2022-04-10&gde=2022-09-12&z=1663107181')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['mlb'])
print(df)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
    Date    Opp teamid  season  Team    HomeAway    Age W   L   ERA G   GS  CG  ShO SV  HLD BS  IP  TBF H   R   ER  HR  BB  IBB HBP WP  BK  SO  K/9 BB/9    H/9 K/BB    IFH%    BUH%    GB  FB  LD  IFFB    IFH BU  BUH K%  BB% K-BB%   SIERA   HR/9    AVG WHIP    BABIP   LOB%    FIP E-F xFIP    ERA-    FIP-    xFIP-   GB/FB   LD% GB% FB% IFFB%   HR/FB   RS  RS/9    Balls   Strikes Pitches WPA -WPA    +WPA    RE24    REW pLI inLI    gmLI    exLI    Pulls   Games   WPA/LI  Clutch  SD  MD  FB%1    FBv SL% SLv CH% CHv wFB wSL wCH wFB/C   wSL/C   wCH/C   O-Swing%    Z-Swing%    Swing%  O-Contact%  Z-Contact%  Contact%    Zone%   F-Strike%   SwStr%  Pull    Cent    Oppo    Soft    Med Hard    bipCount    Pull%   Cent%   Oppo%   Soft%   Med%    Hard%   PlayerName  playerid    tERA    GSv2    pfxFA%  pfxSI%  pfxSL%  pfxCH%  pfxvFA  pfxvSI  pfxvSL  pfxvCH  pfxFA-X pfxSI-X pfxSL-X pfxCH-X pfxFA-Z pfxSI-Z pfxSL-Z pfxCH-Z pfxwFA  pfxwSI  pfxwSL  pfxwCH  pfxwFA/C    pfxwSI/C    pfxwSL/C    pfxwCH/C    pfxO-Swing% pfxZ-Swing% pfxSwing%   pfxO-Contact%   pfxZ-Contact%   pfxContact% pfxZone%    pfxPace piCH%   piFA%   piSI%   piSL%   piXX%   pivCH   pivFA   pivSI   pivSL   pivXX   piCH-X  piFA-X  piSI-X  piSL-X  piXX-X  piCH-Z  piFA-Z  piSI-Z  piSL-Z  piXX-Z  piwCH   piwFA   piwSI   piwSL   piwXX   piwCH/C piwFA/C piwSI/C piwSL/C piwXX/C piO-Swing%  piZ-Swing%  piSwing%    piO-Contact%    piZ-Contact%    piContact%  piZone% Events  EV  LA  Barrels Barrel% maxEV   HardHit HardHit%    gamedate    dh
0   <a href="/wins.aspx?date=2050-01-01&team=total&dh=0">2050-01-01</a> - - -   20  2022    - - -   A   24  4.0 11.0    5.349057    22.0    22.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 106.0   470.0   113.0   67.0    63.0    14.0    44.0    0.0 5.0 5.0 0.0 105.0   8.915095    3.735849    9.594340    2.386364    0.067669    0.5 133.0   112.0   69.0    5.0 9.0 2.0 1.0 0.223404    0.093617    0.129787    4.186245    1.188679    0.268409    1.481132    0.327815    0.667135    4.243406    1.105651    4.094434    134.238531  107.477754  101.526711  1.187500    0.219745    0.423567    0.356688    0.044643    0.125000    50.0    4.245283    685.0   1223.0  1908.0  -1.919216   -9.791034   7.871818    -15.8036    -1.638929e+00   0.998163    0.882337    0.867627    1.019309    22.0    22.0    -1.502681   -0.420067   0.0 0.0 0.527254    94.645129   0.179769    80.728863   0.292977    85.706619   -8.878565   -1.319738   -2.106202   -0.882561   -0.384763   -0.376780   0.322813    0.715539    0.487153    0.695531    0.826620    0.776103    0.418458    0.612766    0.109015    133.0   109.0   74.0    62.0    162.0   92.0    316.0   0.420886    0.344937    0.234177    0.196203    0.512658    0.291139    Trevor Rogers   22286   4.566455    45.0    0.525157    0.002096    0.179769    0.292977    94.608583   94.849997   80.678718   85.654563   8.065439    11.7475 -3.389592   9.090555    8.385319    3.2725  3.808251    1.335760    -7.785403   -0.614196   -1.246096   -1.899808   -0.776986   -15.354905  -0.363293   -0.339858   0.298838    0.674298    0.487945    0.660777    0.824074    0.774436    0.503669    23.385816   0.292453    0.524633    0.002096    0.179769    0.001048    85.611075   94.589424   94.797028   80.623514   91.021751   8.324599    7.148858    10.731025   -4.301155   5.42764 0.261684    7.435025    2.438555    2.763215    6.392905    -1.972312   -7.847004   -0.614196   -1.246096   0.134105    -0.353461   -0.783916   -15.354905  -0.363293   6.705273    0.298319    0.675732    0.487421    0.665493    0.823529    0.775269    0.501048    316.0   88.299055   11.857416   23.0    0.072785    113.824 116.0   0.367089    2050-01-01  0
1   <a href="/wins.aspx?date=2022-09-12&team=Marlins&dh=1">2022-09-12</a>   TEX 20  2022    MIA H   24  0.0 0.0 2.842105    1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 6.1 24.0    4.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 9.0 12.789474   2.842105    5.684211    4.500000    0.000000    0.0 7.0 3.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.375000    0.083333    0.291667    2.394518    0.000000    0.181818    0.947368    0.307692    0.666667    1.226027    1.616078    1.928979    71.324734   32.517111   48.896813   2.333333    0.230769    0.538462    0.230769    0.000000    0.000000    2.0 2.842105    29.0    60.0    89.0    0.034852    -0.393320   0.428172    0.9269  9.934618e-02    0.979617    1.082800    0.870000    3.073200    1.0 1.0 0.203277    -0.167700   0.0 0.0 0.573034    94.980392   0.067416    83.500000   0.359551    86.156250   0.518355    0.342558    0.944681    1.016382    5.709294    2.952127    0.301887    0.750000    0.483146    0.500000    0.740741    0.651163    0.404494    0.583333    0.168539    4.0 5.0 4.0 1.0 8.0 4.0 13.0    0.307692    0.384615    0.307692    0.076923    0.615385    0.307692    Trevor Rogers   22286   1.677209    68.0    0.573034    NaN 0.067416    0.359551    94.907839   NaN 83.483337   86.134377   9.537647    NaN -1.148333   10.087188   8.466666    NaN 4.296667    1.082500    0.518355    NaN 0.342558    0.944681    1.016382    NaN 5.709294    2.952127    0.325581    0.652174    0.494382    0.500000    0.700000    0.636364    0.516854    20.453125   0.359551    0.573034    NaN 0.067416    NaN 86.203064   94.993490   NaN 83.560450   NaN 9.029422    8.369133    NaN -2.768143   NaN -0.289749   7.267294    NaN 2.612752    NaN 0.944681    0.518355    NaN 0.342558    NaN 2.952127    1.016382    NaN 5.709294    NaN 0.325581    0.652174    0.494382    0.500000    0.700000    0.636364    0.516854    13.0    92.482628   2.117006    1.0 0.076923    105.379 6.0 0.461538    2022-09-12  1
2   <a href="/wins.aspx?date=2022-09-07&team=Marlins&dh=0">2022-09-07</a>   @PHI    20  2022    MIA A   24  0.0 1.0 4.500000    1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 6.0 23.0    5.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 8.0 12.000000   0.000000    7.500000    8.000000    0.166667    0.0 6.0 6.0 3.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.347826    0.000000    0.347826    2.000855    3.000000    0.217391    0.833333    0.230769    0.909091    4.787431    -0.287431   1.938107    112.930823  120.992954  49.118658   1.000000    0.200000    0.400000    0.400000    0.000000    0.333333    2.0 3.000000    30.0    57.0    87.0    -0.059300   -0.440200   0.380900    0.0000  -3.725290e-09   0.804167    0.915000    0.920000    0.750000    1.0 1.0 -0.103264   0.029523    0.0 0.0 0.620690    94.185185   0.160920    82.428571   0.218391    85.947368   2.034562    -0.678451   -1.764662   3.767707    -4.846082   -9.287697   0.318182    0.674419    0.494253    0.642857    0.862069    0.790698    0.494253    0.608696    0.103448    9.0 4.0 2.0 2.0 8.0 5.0 15.0    0.600000    0.266667    0.133333    0.133333    0.533333    0.333333    Trevor Rogers   22286   4.851247    52.0    0.620690    NaN 0.160920    0.218391    94.181478   NaN 82.321429   85.836843   9.481296    NaN -0.274286   10.177368   8.612408    NaN 4.684286    1.065789    2.034562    NaN -0.678451   -1.764662   3.767707    NaN -4.846082   -9.287697   0.238095    0.733333    0.494253    0.600000    0.848485    0.790698    0.517241    22.000000   0.218391    0.620690    NaN 0.160920    NaN 86.182418   94.539867   NaN 82.674308   NaN 8.901917    8.122533    NaN -1.927560   NaN -0.384359   7.333927    NaN 2.989588    NaN -1.764662   2.034562    NaN -0.678451   NaN -9.287697   3.767707    NaN -4.846082   NaN 0.250000    0.702128    0.494253    0.600000    0.848485    0.790698    0.540230    15.0    89.261637   23.314498   2.0 0.133333    109.308 7.0 0.466667    2022-09-07  0
[...]
```

Data returned is quite extensive: you can slice & dice it further, to get what you want from there.

For relevant pandas documentation, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html